# Buck converter freewheeling diode short circuit damaging the FET

Tags: diodes, buck, converter, powermosfet

I have a classic buck converter configuration (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buck_converter) with IXFK120N65X2 power mosfet used as switch and VS-8ETL06PbF used as freewheeling diode. The input voltage is 300VDC, PWM frequency 50kHz, power mosfet driven by ADUM3123 isolated gate driver, DC/DC supply for the high side is MEJ1S0512SC. Max. continuous current is limited to 10A.
It is a prototype and the only I have.

a) When the mosfet is fully switched on (PWM duty = 100%) the converter operates fine for hours - here it seems to be fine.

b) When the buck converter operates in discontinuous mode (i.e. bigger PWM duty and small load OR smaller PWM duty and bigger load) the converter operates fine for hours and all measured waveforms correspond to our SPICE simulations - here it seems to be fine as well.

c) But when the buck converter operates in continuous mode the diode burns within just seconds and in most cases the power mosfet burns as well, causing short circuit of the buck converter and overload protection of our input voltage source to become active. When inspecting the damaged parts after this event, the diode is then fully conductive with zero resistance in both directions and the mosfet sometimes as well (zero resistance between drain and source).

I've experienced 5 those "crashes" before I could isolate the event to occur only in the continuous mode. I think the cause here is a fairly long reverse recovery time of this diode, causing repetitive short circuits during each reverse recovery cycle which finally destroy the diode after few seconds. But I am not sure. Maybe also this diode is not suitable for this purpose. Because the operating time ad c) was always very short I was not able to measure anything. Now I don't want to destroy more diodes and FETs. I already ordered a SiC diode alternative (which has a slightly higher forward voltage however) and will try it again then.

Question: Did you experience such behavior and/or are my assumptions correct?

Thank you

EDIT: Load of the converter is only resistive (a heater).

Comment: Check resonance with wiring L and use twisted pairs and consider snubber RC. Then include that in simulation with wiring L.

Comment: "Hyperfast recovery time" lol got to love sales people... However, if it was recovery time I'd still expect your diode to fry when using short PWM cycles since the switching events would be identical. Since it is happening on high loads I'd suspect the currents and voltages involved instead. BTW heaters can have significant inductance.

Comment: hyper marketing people (lol)

Comment: You may want to add an appropriate small resistance in series with the flyback diode to limit the current though.

Comment: Showing us the driver stage schematic might also help us see anything odd.

Comment: Or use a low ESR RF cap on output to prevent flyback. The purpose of a Buck is to generate DC out so load L should not be a factor when switch off in continuous mode. if output cap is low ESR.

Comment: Thank you Tony and Trevor. I will try the SiC diode instead and if it does not help I'll consider your proposals.

Comment: @Trevor: It also happens on small loads (even less than 1/4 of maximum nominal load) if the PWM duty is high enough so that the converter operates in continuous mode.

Comment: Then I am a tad confused by your description #b where you seem to imply it works fine on small loads.

Comment: It works only fine in discontinuous mode. 

For smaller loads it allows higher PWM duty, for bigger loads you have to decrease the PWM duty to make it work.

If the load is small but PWM duty is high enough so that the converter goes to continuous mode then it burns as well.

EDIT: I'll add oscillograms when the SiC diode does not help to make it clearer to you.

Comment: A scope trace of the switching node would be nice. Who knows, you might catch a huge LC oscillation, slow recovery, or other problems.

Comment: If it works fine in discontinuous mode and suddenly fries  in continuous mode it might be a control loop issue. The control to output transfer function is different between the two conditions and you might be getting damaging oscillations in continuous mode.  Is your controller using peak current mode?  If so do you have slope compensation to avoid subharmonic oscillations?  (Though they are usually not fatal to the converter.)

Comment: @JohnD agreed, if inductor current is too high or inductor saturates then the FET and the diode would overheat. OP: if you got a current probe, scope the inductor current, else scope the voltage on output cap, it gives a good insight into the current.

Comment: @JohnD: I didn't even come close to any control loop here but thank you for hints for future. Now I just set the PWM duty in the uP manually and do not care much about output voltage value. The PWM goes from uP pin directly to ADUM3123 which then turns the FET on/off via a 5Ohm gate resistor (here everything ok on the high side - inspected with a battery scope - and everything ok on the switching node in discontinous mode as well).

Comment: @peufeu: When the SiC diode does not help then there must be some other cause, such as that you describe with some LC parasitic oscillation. I have to find out how to "catch" the respective waveforms in continous mode before it burns again. Idea that I also have is to put a suitable varistor or HV TVS diode (transil) across the diode.

Comment: Well if you don't have a feedback loop and current sense then what detects overcurrent and prevents the FET from burning?

Comment: @peufeu: Overload protection circuitry will be done later on 2nd sample. Now the sample I have is without this. I admit perhaps the FETs could be saved when there was overload protection but it isn't there now. And feedback loop will not be part of this converter anyway - it will be part of a superior system which will independently measure the output power of attached heater and adjust the PWM duty (via a 0-10VDC input control signal) according to many different conditions.

Comment: OK, before it was a buck converter, now it's a PWM heater which is completely different. You really need to post schematics so we know what we're talking about.

Comment: @peufeu: No it is buck converter: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buck_converter. Load is resistive heater (L really negligible). But I'll add schematics when I get permission to do that, if the diode replacement does not help.

Comment: if you don't have permissions, put them in the comments, I'll add them to your post

Comment: What's your inductor? And take a picture of the circuit as implemented. The physical design matters.

Comment: It was most probably the diode issue. Changed to SiC IDH06G65C6XKSA1 and experienced no event since then. But it needs more testing. I'll report later.